# Unable to click a button in a pageBlockTable with JQuery

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have a Visualforce SPA that is working well but I cannot display an alert or perform any other operation with JQuery when clicking a button inside a pageBlockTable. I found that using the span tag id was visible to jquery when using the commandButton, yet it is not working inside the pageblocktable, only when placed outside of it which isn't the requirement. There is a button per record. The server side code runs fine when clicking the commandButton. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false" controller="schinternal_Cntrl">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>          

</head>

<style>

</style>

<!--STRIPPED DOWN VERSION FOR SHARING -->

<apex:form id="myform">    

<div class="container-fluid">       


    <div id="pg_schedule">                                                                                         

      <h4 class="page-header">Available</h4>                    

      <apex:pageBlock id="pb_detail" title="">

        <apex:pageBlockTable id="slottable" value="{!slotLst}" var="sl" cellPadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1" style="" styleClass="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">

            <apex:column headerValue="Select">                
                <span id="btn_scheduleapp">
                <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-success" action="{!saveApp}" value="Select" rerender="pb_detail">        
                   <apex:param name="sId" value="{!sl.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedSlot}"/>
                </apex:commandButton> 
                </span>                                                                                     
            </apex:column>  

            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Id</apex:facet>            
                <apex:outputText value="{!sl.Id}"/>
            </apex:column>             

        </apex:pageBlockTable>                                                              
      </apex:pageBlock>

    </div>  

 </div>    

<script type="text/javascript">

 var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

 j$(function() {
   j$("#btn_backtofirst").click(function() {
   j$("#pg_firstpage").show(); 
   j$("#pg_schedule").hide(); 
   }); 
 })


 j$(function() {
   j$("#btn_scheduleapp").click(function() {     
   alert('Please review the newly created appointment for this request.')  
   j$("#btn_backtofirst").click();//call the back to first button click  
   }); 
 })

</script>


  </apex:form>        
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this by relying on JavaScript as opposed to just JQuery. Adding the onClick right on the commandButton worked with JS but I was breaking my head trying to make it work with JQuery. I'm no expert so I don't know the why, but I'm very happy that it works.

```
            <apex:column headerValue="Select">                
                <apex:commandButton id="btn_scheduleapp" styleClass="btn btn-success" action="{!saveApp}" value="Select" rerender="pb_detail" onClick="submitSchedule();">        
                   <apex:param name="sId" value="{!sl.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedSlot}"/>
                </apex:commandButton>                                                                                   
            </apex:column>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function submitSchedule(){
     alert('Please review the newly created appointment for this request.')  
  } 

</script>
```